# Powershell, PsExec and remote installs

Tags: powershell, psexec, software-distribution

I am deploying Internet Explorer on remote PCs via Powershell and PsExec. After checking of the target PC is available, this excerpt of code:

```
     $computer = "MYCOMPUTER"
     $arguments = "/quiet /closeprograms /norestart /log:C:\"
     $execname = "C:\IE11-Windows6.1-x64-en-us.exe"
     $cmdinstall = "`"$execname`" -ArgumentList $arguments"
     & C:\PSScripts\Installs\PsExec.exe \\$computer $cmdinstall
```

Is used to do the remote install. Is this the correct syntax for the arguments, and what else can I do to ensure a smooth mass install, and how can I obtain `InstallStatus` return variable? [The documentation on IE installs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn454904.aspx) does note `InstallStatus` is available.
[EDIT] Ignore InstallStatus bit, it looks like it gets stored in the registry.

At the moment, running this script seems to connect, execute the command and just hangs.

I've also tried a script [like this one](https://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/2311-install-software-remotely), but same issue. The installer provider by Microsoft (IE11-Windows6.1-x64-en-us.exe) does not seem to complete, and I cannot find a log file. I cannot tell if my script is the issue or not?

Comment: To start, you appear to be installing IE11 and referencing IE8 command line options. You should really look at the [IE11 command line options](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn321443.aspx) for third party installations.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Most of those still apply, except `log`. How can I output a log?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician This seems to indicate `log` is acceptable https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn454904.aspx

Comment: Start by running the commands locally, get that perfect then just put that into a batch file and use Psexec to push that to the remote system. Run under System but System only has access to Local resources.